# The Dialog for Google In-App review is not visible but gives a success message

Tags: java, android

I have implemented the Google In-App Review API and tried out using the Internal-Testing Track on Google Play Console but for some reason, the Dialog for posting the review is not visible but the flow gives me a successful Toast Message.
This is the code -

```
public static void activeReviewInfo(Activity activity) {
        manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(activity);
        com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task<ReviewInfo> managerInfoTask = manager.requestReviewFlow();
        managerInfoTask.addOnCompleteListener((task) -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                reviewInfo = task.getResult();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Review Failed To Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
    public static void startReviewFlow(Activity activity){
        if(reviewInfo!=null){
            com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task<Void> flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(activity,reviewInfo);
            flow.addOnCompleteListener(new com.google.android.play.core.tasks.OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(activity,"Rating is Complete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(activity,"Rating is not Complete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Google explicitly mention in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review#quotas) that they do not guarantee that the dialog will show if the API is called multiple times:

> To provide a great user experience, Google Play enforces a time-bound quota on how often a user can be shown the review dialog. Because of this quota, calling the `launchReviewFlow` method more than once during a short period of time (for example, less than a month) might not always display a dialog.

Test your app using Play Internal App Sharing to bypass that time-bound quota thing, as instructed [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test#internal-app-sharing).